# WordPress: White screen of death after failed to verify site ownership

Tags: wordpress

Today, I received an E-mail from Google informing me about some page-indexing problems, when I checked it, it asked me to verify site ownership but I didn't verify it.

And since then, whenever I try to open any page of my site it shows a white screen and nothing else.

Tried to enable 'debug' in wp-config file but it doesn't show any error.

Also, when I try to edit any post or page after I have successfully logged into my wp-admin panel of my site it fails to update.

Please give me your guidance, thanks.

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. Maybe consider posting to wordpress.stackexchange.com but please read their guidelines first, and provide all relevant information/details. Also: no need adding comments asking for help: this isn't a paid support site, and there is no notion of SLA or time window for answering questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the list of probably causes,

- File permission - Wordpress recommends 755 for all directories
- File Permission - Also recommends 644 for all files
- Wrong folder path of your Theme

Important Note:
Make sure to generate a backup.